# decoding strings in the ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to decode the strings from the database, but when I try to use this code in an ActionLink the encoded values still display.

```
var questionText = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionText);
var decodedText = @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(questionText.ToString()));

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
       <h4>@Html.ActionLink(decodedText.ToHtmlString(), "Edit", new { id = item.QuestionId })</h4>
     }
```

What needs to be done for the text to display correctly in the ActionLink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IHtmlString` (which `Html.Raw()` returns) is only recognized by raw `@` expresisons; not by other helper methods.

You need to write an `<a>` tag yourself.